# Get the current URL and append new paramater in that URL

Tags: java, jsf

In my application, I am receiving one URL with different parameters. I need to check if “locale” parameter is present in the parameter or not. If the parameter is present in the URL then I need to modify the value and if the parameter is not present then I need to add the URL.

For this requirement how I can create new URL which will be having existing URL with “locale” parameter?

Comment: Can you share your code to help you better.

Comment: You might want to use a [Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html)

Comment: Use a Filter for this. You can check an example from [StackOverflow Servlet-Filter wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlet-filters/info)

Comment: @user2625662 you must edit your question and provide the code **there** instead of posting code in comments.

Comment: With the below code i am getting the current URL. I need to generate new URL with the "locale" parameter. FacesContext facesContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(); String viewId = facesContext.getViewRoot().getViewId(); String path = facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequestContextPath(); String URL=path+viewId

Comment: Filter? OP just needs <f:param> or <o:form>. He just asked the question the wrong way. He faced a problem, thought about a "possible" solution and asked a question about how to achieve *that* solution. However, this solution is after all completely wrong. OP should initially have asked about the original problem, so that right solution can be proposed in an answer. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem and OP's follow-up question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17925415/httpservletrequest-is-not-working-for-retrieving-parameter-from-url

Comment: I am not passing the parameter to JSF page. so i dont want to use <f:param> or <o:form>. I am trying to get the existing URL with the parameter name and values

Answer (score -3):

1. Fetch the query part of the urL
2. Use regex to replace the locale param
3. Create a new URL with the query from #2

   URL url = new URL("http://www.blablabla.com?a=3&locale=us&b=4");
   String newQuery = url.getQuery().replaceAll("locale=.+?&", "locale=bla");